# dnndev.me works on chrome and firefox browser but not IE

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, iis-8, dotnetnuke-7

I have a win 8.1 pc with sql server epxress 2012 and iis 8.  I set up the dnndev.me testing environment as per @christoc tutorial [HERE](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/aid/1).

This works perfectly when i request the dnndev.me page in CHrome, Firefox, and safari.  But IE will not display this page.

I get the following screen:

[image]

I have a binding for both www.dnndev.me and dnndev.me.  I am not sure what is going one here because the site is getting serverd up properly to the other browsers so I know that the permissions are not an issue.

### Question:

Can someone help me figure out why the local DNN site will not display in IE?

### EDIT 1:

This is what I added to the host file that was mentioned by Chris:

```
127.0.0.1       dnndev.me
127.0.0.1       www.dnndev.me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is IE using a proxy server? I would guess that IE is not resolving the domain name properly, you might try adding 127.0.0.1 dnndev.me to your hosts file in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\ in case IE isn't getting the public DNS records for that domain name.

edit: You might also try running Fiddler to see if the requests are going external, instead of internal when run through IE.

Also, double check that it isn't just a "Default" document issue, put default.aspx on the end of the URL

Comment: thanks, I already tried that, added dnndev.me and www.dnndev.me to the host file, restarted the site and recycled the app pool and it did not work.  This is odd.

Comment: I checked the connection (LAN) settings for IE and I am not using a proxy server.

Comment: Updated answer with a couple more suggestions

Comment: I requested the default.aspx and it did not work.  So I moved on to trying fiddler.  I have never used fiddler before.  Neat tool. As for the solution, after I installed Fiddler and configured it to run for win 8,  I requested dnndev.me in IE and it worked.  Something in the install and configuration of fiddler somehow fixed the issue.  Wish I had a more specific reason/solution but I'll take it.  Thanks for sticking with it.